# Node module (@pusher/push-notifications-web) failing to import on refreshing page - nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, pusher

facing this issue while integrating node module `@pusher/push-notifications-web` https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-web

I am not sure if this is an issue with NextJs or with the node module itself.

Everything works fine when the pages load for the first time, but when by any chance if we refresh the page or redirect the user to a new page. I am getting this error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import ES module in Next.js ERR\_REQUIRE\_ESM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974337/import-es-module-in-next-js-err-require-esm)

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by transpiling `@pusher/push-notifications-web` module -  which is exported as ESM - using `next-transpile-modules` in Next.js config:

```js
// next.config.js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@pusher/push-notifications-web']);

module.exports = withTM({/* custom config */});
```