# Import ES module in Next.js ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, next.js, es6-modules

I came upon this error when trying to use [`ky`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) in a Next.js project:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /foo/node_modules/ky/index.js

I think the problem is that Webpack (or Babel) is transforming all `import`s to `require()`s but [`ky` is a pure ES module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky-universal/releases/tag/v0.9.0).

I got it working by dynamically importing `ky` before using it but it's not elegant nor efficient.

```
const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
  const ky = (await import("ky")).default;

  const response = await ky
    .get('http://localhost/api/foo')
    .json();
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From Next.js 12, [support for ES Modules](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#es-modules-support-and-url-imports) is now enabled by default, as long as the ESM library has `"type": "module"` in its `package.json`. Using `next-transpile-modules` to transpile ESM libraries is no longer required.

---

##### Before Next.js 12

Since `ky` is exported as ESM you can transpile it with [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) in `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['ky']);

module.exports = withTM(/* your Next.js config */);
```

Comment: I had this same problem trying to use `unist-util-visit` @3.1.0. This is the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: I also faced a similar issue with three.js and this solved my problem. Additional link that helped w/ my issue: https://website-git-switcher-pmndrs.vercel.app/react-three-fiber/getting-started/installation#next-js

Comment: In Next.js 12 I still hit this issue with the following build command `esbuild index.ts --outdir=dist --sourcemap --bundle --minify --platform=neutral --main-fields=module,main,browser`

It builds as ESM, but then importing my module in _app.js stills throws this error

Comment: @EricBurel Do you have `"type": "module"` in the lib's `package.json`?

Comment: Yep. I'll build a repro/demo here: https://github.com/VulcanJS/npm-the-right-way, I've started to document our build process for full stack packages and compare technologies. I've tried with Next 12 but Webpack 4 only so maybe that's related.

Comment: I now advice anyone not to use NextJs they've introduce massive breaking change with this and SWC.

Answer (score 5):

You can try upgrading nextjs to v11.1.0, it has some support for ESM.

See: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/27069

More info in this issue discussion from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9607#issuecomment-906155992

Comment: That's really neat!

Comment: Awesome, that did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since Next.js 12 ([official announcement](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#es-modules-support-and-url-imports)), support for ESM modules is automatically enabled. See [#29878](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/29878).

Since Next.js 12.1, you can add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`. See [#33637](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/33637).

Answer (score 0):

**NextJS 12** (and maybe 13?) and **TypeScript**: please see this [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9607#issuecomment-693021546), then add `--esm` to your `"dev"` line in your main `package.json` as this user suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75162768/3997521), and finally, update (or make sure) your `tsconfig.server.json` (inherits from tsconfig.json) says `"module": "ESNext"` instead of `"module": "commonjs"`.