# Support ESM in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm making some optimation on nextjs project and need to has `type: 'module'` on the`package.json` file. But then got the error

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
> my_path/next.config.js require() of ES modules is not supported.

Seem next.config.js is not support ESM yet.
The issue already discussed here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9607 but I can find a solution yet.
Any help guys?

I'm using:
`node v12.17.0`
`next 11.1.0`

And here is my next.config.js

```
import withLess from '@zeit/next-less'

const nextConfig = {
  target: 'serverless',
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
  webpack5: true,
  onDemandEntries: {
    maxInactiveAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    pagesBufferLength: 5
  },
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true
  },
  trailingSlash: false,
}

export default withLess(nextConfig)
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "type": "module"
  ...
}
```

UPDATE:
What I optimated is changing the way to call Component from `'ant'` package.

Form

```
import { Row, Col } from 'antd'
```

To

```
import Row from 'antd/es/row'
import Col from 'antd/es/col'
```

then cause this error

> my_path/node_modules/antd/es/row/index.js:1
>
> import { Row } from '../grid'; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I fixed this by add `type: "module"` in `package.json` and have problem with `next.config.js` file

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974337/import-es-module-in-next-js-err-require-esm

Comment: *"I'm making some optimizations on Next.js project and need to has type: 'module'"* -- can I know what optimizations you are referring to? Cause IMHO only files related with your custom server are not processed by babel/webpack, and hence don't support ESM syntax by default, but can be made so by simply changing their extension to `.mjs`. What is the need to modify `package.json` to indicate `type: module` at the first place?

Comment: @brc-dd updated in post

Comment: @bird So I guess you did that because for some reasons `antd`'s tree shaking wasn't working for you. Right?

Comment: @brc-dd yes, right. I am trying another way. That's config the webpack

Comment: @bird If the main issue is to consume an ESM library in your Next.js app, have you tried Camilo's suggested link: [Import ES module in Next.js ERR_REQUIRE_ESM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65978156/1870780)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Next.js 12, ES modules is now supported in the [config file](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction) by renaming it to `next.config.mjs`.

```
// next.config.mjs
import withLess from '@zeit/next-less'

export default withLess({
    productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
    onDemandEntries: {
        maxInactiveAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
        pagesBufferLength: 5
    },
    lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true
    },
    trailingSlash: false
})
```

Comment: having next.config.mjs and ```type: 'module'``` in package.json results in error: require() of ES Module /usr/app/.next/server/pages/_document.js from /usr/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js not supported.

Comment: You only need to pick one or the other: you can *either* rename every file to `.mjs` *or* you can add `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.