# NextJS config: Move redirects to it's own file

Tags: next.js

I'm moving from a wordpress site to a new, shiny nextjs site. However, I have hundreds of redirects and I don't want to put them all in the nextjs config file. I like things clean and tidy. I searched around for awhile and didn't find any results on how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have them in the config file. The `redirects` property in `next.config.js` is an async function, you could move the logic to generate the redirects to a helper and just call the function in the config.

Comment: @juliomalves could you be a bit more specific on how to call that function from within next.config.js? I've tried importing the helper function as well as requiring it as a const and neither are working

Comment: @juliomalves Hey so I tried adding this to my nextjs.config: 
`import { redirects } from '@lib/helpers'`
and got the following error: 
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Use `require` instead, i.e. `const redirects = require('@lib/helpers').redirects`. Or convert your config file to ESM so you can use `import`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781269/1870780.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import it via require, tho remember that u also need to export it as module, so ex.:

```
const redirectsArray = [
  { source: "/about", destination: "/", permanent: true },
];

async function redirects() {
  return redirectsArray;
}

module.exports = {
  redirects,
};
```

and then

```
const { redirects } = require("./redirects.js");
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. How would I then add the redirects into my main config after importing them as a const?

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. You just add it as a line under the main config settings.

Comment: Like so: 
`const { redirects } = require("./src/app/lib/redirects.ts");
const nextConfig = { redirects };
module.exports = nextConfig;
`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working while module exporting it as an array instead of an object in the redirects.js

```
module.exports = redirects
```

And then add it to the next.config.js like so

```
 async redirects() {
     return redirects
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The above helped a lot but took some time to get right. Here's a clear summary.

(1) Create redirects.ts in the root and put in eg:

```
const redirects = [
  { source: "/test1", destination: "/test2", permanent: true },
];

module.exports = {
  redirects,
};
```

(2) At the top of your next.config.js:

```
const { redirects } = require("./redirects.ts");
```

(3) Then later in next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  async redirects() {
    return redirects;
  },
  ...
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```