# Using Remark and Rehype plugins with MDX in Next.js (with @next/mdx)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown, mdxjs

I was trying to use Github Flavored Markdown using `@next/mdx` but I can't seem to figure out how to use plugins with the code.  Here is what I did:

(I am following along from Next.js Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx)

---

#### Initializing the Application

**1.** I created the Next.js App using the command

```
yarn create next-app next-gfm
```

**2.** I then added the required modules to the

```
yarn add @next/mdx @mdx-js/loader
```

**3.** In the `pages/` directory, I deleted the `index.js` file that was auto generated and replaced it using a `index.mdx` file.

From here, I used the following configuration for my `next.config.js` file.

```js
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
})

module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
})
```

If we run the code using `yarn dev` everything works fine so far.

#### Adding GFM

Here is where the main issue is. I now installed the following packages to use Github Flavored Markdown using the command:

```
yarn add remark-gfm rehype-stringify
```

##### Import Syntax Error?

I tried to import the modules in the `next.config.js` using the syntax

```js
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

##### Making the project a `module`

I have also tried adding the following line at the top of my `package.json`

```json
"type" : "module",
```

But this seems to conflict with the require syntax that is being used to import `@next/mdx`:

```js
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
...
```

This gave me the error:

```
Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

##### Using older `import()` syntax

I did a bit of searching online, and found the `import()` syntax. I attempted to do this and my `next.config.js` now looked like:

```js
const remarkGfm  = import('remark-gfm');
const remarkParse  = import('remark-parse')
const remarkRehype  = import('remark-rehype')
const rehypeStringify  = import('rehype-stringify')

const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm, remarkParse, remarkRehype],
    rehypePlugins: [rehypeStringify],
  },
})

module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
})
```

I tried running this, using the `yarn dev` and everything works, except that none of the markdown plugins are functioning at all. (The base markdown is working but if I try using footnotes, or tables it is rendered as plain text).

Could anyone explain how one might proceed using external plugins (e.g Github Flavored Markdown) with MDX and Next.js (using the `@next/mdx` package)?

##### Reference

This is my complete project structure and (relevant) files:

```
next-gfm
  |_ pages
       |_ index.md
  |_ package.json
  |_ next.config.js
```

##### Files

`index.md`

```
# GFM

## Autolink literals

www.example.com, https://example.com, and contact@example.com.

## Footnote

A note[^1]

[^1]: Big note.

## Strikethrough

~one~ or ~~two~~ tildes.

## Table

| a | b  |  c |  d  |
| - | :- | -: | :-: |

## Tasklist

* [ ] to do
* [x] done
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "next-mdx-template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.1.1",
    "@next/mdx": "^12.1.5",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "rehype-katex": "^6.0.2",
    "rehype-stringify": "^9.0.3",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "remark-math": "^5.1.1",
    "remark-mdx": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5"
  }
}
```

`next.config.js`

```js
const remarkGfm  = import('remark-gfm');
const remarkParse  = import('remark-parse')
const remarkRehype  = import('remark-rehype')
const rehypeStringify  = import('rehype-stringify')

const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm, remarkParse, remarkRehype],
    rehypePlugins: [rehypeStringify],
  },
})

module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES Modules are supported if you rename the config file to `next.config.mjs`.

Sources

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781269/4811678
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction

In your case it might look like,

`next.config.mjs`

```js
import nextMDX from '@next/mdx'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import remarkRehype from 'remark-rehype'
import rehypeStringify from 'rehype-stringify'

const withMDX = nextMDX({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm, remarkParse, remarkRehype],
    rehypePlugins: [rehypeStringify],
  },
})

export default withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**next-mdx-remote** users:

Run `npm i remark-gfm`

Create a file `mdSerializer.ts`, and inside:

```
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';

const mdSerialize = async (source: string) => {
  return await serialize(source, {
    mdxOptions: { remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm] },
  });
};

export { mdSerialize };
```

Import `mdSerialize` anywhere you'd normally import `serialize`

---

For more details around the `serialize` API, [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote#apis)

`Gfm` example from the original mdx site, [here](https://mdxjs.com/guides/gfm/)