# ReactJS Library being used in NextJS project says is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have built a ReactJS library and published it to NPM and works fine in a standard ReactJS project, but I now have a NextJS and I am trying to add it there, I expected it would just work as NextJS is a framework on top of ReactJS with some additional functionality.

In the app.js I have the following:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import {useEffect} from "react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    const {CrashCatch, CrashCatchProvider} = dynamic(import('crashcatchlib-reactjs'), { ssr: false })

    let crash_catch = new CrashCatch();

    crash_catch.initialiseCrashCatch("12978650", "d7kqcewvshoyxbp564f8tm0zl", "1.0.1");

    return (
       ....
    ) 
}
```

When running this I get `TypeError: CrashCatch is not a constructor`

I have tried not using a dynamic import and doing a standard import as `import {CrashCatch, CrashCatchProvider} from "crashcatchlib-reactjs";` but then I get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`]

The source code for the reactjs library is open source so it's available on GitHub at https://github.com/Crash-Catch/CrashCatchLib-ReactJS. The index.js has the class CrashCatch which has the constructor so not sure why NextJS is treating it differently.

Comment: You may have a build process that does not interpret the dynamic `import` syntax so it is not included in the runnable bundle

Comment: I don't build my reactjs library as its just a simple JS file so I don't think it needs building - I could very well be mistaken as its my first library I've created. Is there a build process for a standard JS/ReactJS library (I know for Typescript projects there needs to be a build process running tsc)

Comment: Have tried to initialize it inside HOC ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Import ES module in Next.js ERR_REQUIRE_ESM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65978156/1870780)? Try adding `"type": "module"` in your library's `package.json`. Alternatively, use `next-transpile-modules` to transpile the library in your Next.js app.

Comment: Thanks, been a bit tied up the last couple of few days, hoping to pick this up in a couple of days time. What is HOC though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NextJS executes code on the server-side, so your library should also be compatible with Node. It seems import is not supported in CommonJS, which is the default module format used by Node. However, you can specify that your library should be treated as an ES Module to support import statements as described in the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling

> Node.js treats JavaScript code as CommonJS modules by default. Authors can tell Node.js to treat JavaScript code as ECMAScript modules via the .mjs file extension, the package.json "type" field, or the --input-type flag. See Modules: Packages for more details.

You could try setting the `type` property to `module` in your package.json

Comment: Thanks, been a bit tied up the last couple of few days, hoping to pick this up in a couple of days time.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

- I never used `crashcatchlib-reactjs` library. I checked the docs could not understand how they import it. But to solve this error:

  ```
  SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module]
  ```

Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules. If you check the docs, in `next.config.js`

```
// next.config.js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['crashcatchlib-reactjs']); 
module.exports = withTM({});
```

- If it does not solve the issue, try dynamic import way, however, one think you should know `dynamic import` returns Loadable Component. I checked dynamic import works only for components. In order to use `import` stament with that package, you should still add configuration of [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules). Then create a component:

import {CrashCatch } from "crashcatchlib-reactjs";

```
export default function ClientSideComponent(props){
    // Write here the logic.
 
    return <>yourJsxLogicComponent</>;
}
```

Then import this component dynamically:

```
const ClientSideComponent = dynamic(()=> import("./ClientSideComponent.js"), { ssr: false });
```

- In this case use vanilla js dynamic import. I am not sure If you have to add configuration of `next-transpile-modules`.

  ```
  let CrashCatchImport, CrashCatchProviderImport;

  import("crashcatchlib-reactjs").then((CrashCatch, CrashCatchProvider) => 
  {
    CrashCatchImport = CrashCatch.default;
    CrashCatchProviderImport=CrashCatchProvider.default;
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay been a bit tied up, hoping to pick this up again in a couple of days. Out of curiosity, what page did you look at for the docs that you found confusing - was it https://docs.crashcatch.com/integrations/reactjs by any chance. This is my side project that I am working on so I can avoid confusion that would be great :)